# a pythonic way of getting the range of a list that defined in the parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I forced start index equant to the end index to get the whole list, but it's not flexible enough and I wonder if there is a more intuitive/pythonic or better way of defining such function?

```
@click.command()
@click.option("-r", "--range", nargs=2, type=int, help="the start & end index")
def main(range):
    start, end = range
    elements = all_elements[start-1:] if start==end else all_elements[start-1:end]
```

EDIT: I changed the code from `elements = all_elements`, to the `elements = all_elements[start-1:]`, so that when `python main.py 1 100` is called, will return the first 100 items, and `python main.py 5 5` returns all items from 5th.

Comment: good, that nobody complains this ugly solution after months ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more flexible by using a default value for the end argument. You can set it to the length of all_elements so that if only one value is provided, it will select all elements starting from that index:

```
@click.command()
@click.option("-r", "--range", nargs=2, type=int, help="the start & end index")
def main(range):
    start, end = range
    end = len(all_elements) if end is None else end
    elements = all_elements[start-1:end]
```

Alternatively, you could also provide a --all option to select all elements:

```
@click.command()
@click.option("-r", "--range", nargs=2, type=int, help="the start & end index")
@click.option("-a", "--all", is_flag=True, help="select all elements")
def main(range, all):
    if all:
        elements = all_elements
    else:
        start, end = range
        end = len(all_elements) if end is None else end
        elements = all_elements[start-1:end]
```